# Enable Speech on Webchat with BotAuth Dialog

Tags: botframework

In our webchat, we have enabled BotAuth, so that user should be able to login using Azure AD credentials (as follows):

```
await context.Forward(new AuthDialog(new MSALAuthProvider(), options), async (IDialogContext authContext, IAwaitable<AuthResult> authResult) =>
{
    aresult = await authResult;
    ....
}
```

To enable voice, we are using Directline client as described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech

For the first time, Bot displays Login Button and user is able to Login and can see email is sent to his/her id..

For the second time if another user logs in it does not display login button instead it shows  email is sent to First user, somehow first user's token is retained for second user and so on.

If we remove the reference of Webchat.html (that contains directline reference to the Bot the functionality works fine). Seems Directline retains the token, which causes above issue.

To clear directline messages, we have tried [these options](https://www.google.com/search?ei=HKPAW_KLLsPUwALHpKqABg&q=clearing%20directline%20bot%20cache%20messages&oq=clearing%20directline%20bot%20cache%20messages&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2222.5188.0.5692.9.9.0.0.0.0.449.854.4-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.1.404...33i21k1.0.EoNQfaKxQrc), but did not get the exact solution

Any idea on how to fix this?,Also posted the question here
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1208

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Helpful feedback: new begging material was added to this question, so I have downvoted this time.

Answer (score 1):

DirectLine is not retaining the token, your bot is or more specifically, the BotAuth code. 
BotAuth stores three values in BotUserData store. The AuthResultKey, MagicNumberKey and MagicNumberValidated. It uses these to get and refresh the authentication token. Take a look at [MSALAuthProvier.cs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/master/CSharp/BotAuth.AADv2/MSALAuthProvider.cs) is the BotAuth project to see what I'm talking about.

BothAuth is storing the token in an in memory cache, then retrieving or refreshing it as long as it thinks the same user is still 'logged in'. What you need to do is come up with a mechanism in your bot to log out the current user.

Whatever mechanism you decide, to execute the logout simply clear out the three pieces of data being stored in the BotUserData store. You can see where BotAuth is setting these values during the login process in [AuthDialog.cs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/master/CSharp/BotAuth/Dialogs/AuthDialog.cs) in the BotAuth project.

In several bot projects I've worked on I've implemented a direct logout where I prompt the user and ask if they are done and would like to log out. I also track a timestamp of the users last message received. I have a timeout value (usually around five minutes), where if the next message comes in after that five minute span, I silently execute a logout (by clearing those values I mentioned), thus forcing a new login.
Here's a simple example of what Im talking about. This is my MessagesController.cs

```
var userPrivateData = await _botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);

if (!DateTime.TryParse(userPrivateData.GetProperty<string>(Utility.Constants.UserActivityKey), out DateTime userLastActivity))
userLastActivity = DateTime.Now;
Trace.TraceInformation($"MessagesController::User Last Activity : {userLastActivity.ToString()}");

TimeSpan sincelast = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - userLastActivity.Ticks);
if (sincelast > Constants.MaxIdleTimeTicks)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation($"MessagesController::User Last Activity : Idle Timeout. Reset User Auth State");        

    userPrivateData.RemoveProperty($"{Constants.AzureADAuthType}{ContextConstants.AuthResultKey}");
    userPrivateData.RemoveProperty($"{Constants.AzureADAuthType}{ContextConstants.MagicNumberKey}");
    userPrivateData.RemoveProperty($"{Constants.AzureADAuthType}{ContextConstants.MagicNumberValidated}");
}
userPrivateData.SetProperty(Utility.Constants.UserActivityKey, DateTime.Now.ToString());

await _botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userPrivateData, CancellationToken.None);
await _botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response & it has pointed me to the right direction,

context.userdata.clear() in StartAsync method .. this single statement resolved this issue

Basically I was surprised how it is taken care in this url
https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/botname?s='secret'

But while It is integrated in html page with reference of Directlinewebchat.html it did not work out automatically and need to write code line as above